# Volume of parallelepiped formed by stacking diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant, integer-lattices

Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_k$ be square upper-triangular matrices with non-zero determinants $D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_k$. What is the volume of the parallelepiped defined by the columns of the matrix below?
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
A_1 \\ A_2 \\ \vdots \\ A_k
\end{pmatrix}$$
Equivalently, what is the value of 
$\sqrt{\det(B^T B)}$?

Comment: I suspect that there is no nice shortcut or analytic formula to this computation.  The most we can say is either that
$$
B^TB = A_1^TA_1 + \cdots + A_k^TA_k
$$
is a matrix with size equal to that of $A_i$ or that $\operatorname{det}(B^TB)$ may be computed with the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula#Statement).  We might make the latter formula more efficient by noting that some maximal square submatrices clearly have determinant zero due to the upper-triangular structure of the blocks.

Comment: If the blocks are diagonal instead of merely upper-triangular however (as in the title of your post), this whole thing becomes much easier and either approach works.

Comment: It is also notable that if the blocks are diagonal, then the columns of the matrix are  mutually orthogonal so that the volume of the resulting parallelpiped is some sense "obvious".

Comment: A final remark: applying a $QR$ decomposition to $B$ might be a nice approach here.